# jquery :: Why does hover trigger instantly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does the hover event trigger as soon as the page is loaded?

```js
function showSelector(position) {
  alert(position);
}
 
function hideSelector() {
}

$("#1").hover(showSelector(17), hideSelector);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" id="1">sup</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're calling the function instead of referencing it.

```
$("#1").hover(showSelector(17), hideSelector);
//                        ^^^^
```

Using `showSelector(17)` as callback to the `hover` function will call the function first and then assign it's return value to the hover callback. To solve the issue, you can use anonymous function as callback and then call the function inside it with parameters.

```js
function showSelector(position) {
  alert(position);
}

function hideSelector() {}

$("#1").hover(function() {
  // Use anonymous function
  // Call the function with parameter here
  showSelector(17);
}, hideSelector);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" id="1">sup</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are invoking the function by adding `()` at the end, what you can do is to pass a anonymous function as the mouseenter callback which can call  `showSelector` with the desired arguments like

```js
function showSelector(position) {
  alert(position);
}

function hideSelector() {}

$("#1").hover(function() {
  showSelector(17)
}, hideSelector);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" id="1">sup</a>
```