# JQuery Event Firing Prematurely In Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form with multiple inputs. I have a dropdown at the top with a list of record IDs. When someone selects a record ID, an ajax request is fired and that record's attributes are returned. I then dynamically fill out the form with said attributes. One of the attributes that is returned is an array of emails. I don't know how many will be returned.

I have a loop in my `.done` ajax response. I want to create an event handler on each email that is returned that will allow the user to delete the email from the form. My problem is that my events are being fired as the ajax response is loaded into the DOM even though the event is an on`click` event.

Can anyone see why the `delete_email` function is firing on load instead of on click?

See the code below:

```
 ...
$form_post.done(function(data) {
   $('#button').button('reset');
   //success information here
   data = JSON.parse(data);
  for(var i = 0; i < data.emails.length; i++){
       $('#li_' + data.emails[i].id).on('click','#icon_' + data.emails[i].id,delete_email(data.emails[i].id));
  }
});

function delete_email($id){
    alert('hit');
    $('#li_' + $id).hide();
    $('#hidden_' + $id).val('');
}
```

I've tried the following, and it still triggers on the `.post` event.

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.emails.length; i++){
   (function (i) {
    $('#li_' + data.emails[i].id).on('click', '#icon_' + data.emails[i].id, delete_email(data.emails[i].id));
   }(i));
}
```

**ANSWER** - This is what finally worked. Thanks to @Tushar for his help in solving my problem.

```
(function (i) {
    $('#li_' + data.emails[i].id).on('click', '#icon_' + data.emails[i].id, function () {
         delete_email(data.emails[i].id);
     });
}(i));
```

Comment: Change `delete_email(data.emails[i].id)` to `function() { delete_email(data.emails[i].id) });` See [Why does hover trigger instantly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33116064/jquery-why-does-hover-trigger-instantly) for explanation

Comment: I can't reference my `data.emails[i].id` through an anonymous function. That's why I moved it out on its own so I could send it a value. How do I get around this?

Comment: Wrap it in function, see https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/w2nhhL5x/1/

Comment: You have to use anonymous function too, see my first comment. Also check the code in fiddle, use it exactly as it is

Comment: Your fiddler had a small typo in it, however, it worked! Can post your answer and I'll mark it as working!

Comment: Welcome, glad it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`delete_email` appear to be called , not referenced by name at `click` event ?

Try substituting `Function.prototype.bind()` for invocation of `delete_email` , passing `data.emails[i].id` as argument

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.emails.length; i++){
   (function (i) {
     $('#li_' + data.emails[i].id)
    .on('click', '#icon_' + data.emails[i].id
      , delete_email.bind(null, data.emails[i].id)
    );
   }(i));
}
```

---

```js
function delete_email($id){
    console.log($id)
}

var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
   (function (i) {
     $("<div />", {text: i})
    .on("click", delete_email.bind(null, arr[i])
    ).appendTo("body");
   }(i));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Also suggest anonymous function to call function with param, I'd always avoid `bind` as it throws your previous context out of window, in case if OP/you still want to access it, you cannot get it back