# PreventDefault give a TypeError

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-events, preventdefault

This is my line of code:

```
var $hotlinePanel = $('#hotlines-panel');
var $hotlineTile = $('#redirects-tile-6 .redirect-overlay');

$hotlineTile.on('click', togglePanel(event));

function togglePanel(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $hotlinePanel.toggleClass('open');
};
```

This is the console's error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: **ANSWER:** Change `$hotlineTile.on('click', togglePanel(event));` ==> `$hotlineTile.on('click', togglePanel);`. For explanation see [jquery :: Why does hover trigger instantly?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33116074/2025923)

Comment: Welcome! Glad to help. And please don't call _sir_

Answer (score 1):

Just make little change as below:

```
$hotlineTile.on('click', togglePanel);  // remove-(event), call function with name only - function declaration

// function defination

function togglePanel(e){
    e.preventDefaut();
    $hotlinePanel.toggleClass('open');
};
```

**Update:**

**Note:** The `preventDefault()` method does not prevent propagation of an event through the **DOM**. Use the `stopPropagation()` method to handle this.

Comment: omg thanks. and what would I have to do if I want to prevent the default Events from other Objects in the Dom within that function?

Comment: Do you mind explaining why/how this may/will work?

Comment: @Tushar sir, in first line `togglePanel` is a declaration of a function and after that, we define the function body. (  i am a learner in jquery, so correct me if wrong ) thanks

Comment: Okay, add this in answer. And don't call _sir_